# how to assign the size of vector < list <int> >?

Tags: c++, list, vector, stl

I am trying to create **adjacency list** via `vector < list <int> >`, however I don't how to assign the size of the `list<int>`;

I want to specified the size of both `vector< list<int> >` and `list<int>` while declaring them.

see my code;

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<list>

using namespace std;
...

vector< list<int> > adj_list<(number_city);
// here just specified the size of vector< list<int> >.
```

Comment: You can use `vector< list<int>> adj_list<(number_city, std::list<int>(some_size));`. However, it does not sound right. If you want to pre-specify the size of adjacency list, why not use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to specify the size of `vector` when initializing, then

```
vector< list<int> > adj_list(number_city); // construct vector with size = number_city, all the elements are empty (size == 0)
```

If you want to specify the size of `vector` and all the elements' size, then

```
vector< list<int> > adj_list(number_city, list<int>(some_number)); // construct vector with size = number_city and all the elements are lists with some_number elements default constructed
```

See [std::vector's third constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) and [std::list's third constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/list)

Comment: Thanks a lot. @songyuanyao

Answer (score 0):

```
vector< list<int> > adj_list<(number_city);
for(vector< list<int> >::size_type i = 0; i < number_city; i++)
{
    adj_list.at(i).resize(some_size);
}
```

You can try this way.